# Animate the camera with react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-spring, react-three-drei

So what I am trying to do is animate the camera after it finds the mesh id.
Right now it works, but it teleports to the mesh instead of animating the camera to the make. I have tried react-sprint and @react-three/drei, but I just can't figure this out.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shadow-l0yj1s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls (react-three-fiber example)